# How to shadow git's built-in commands?

Tags: git

I'd like to have the following script run when "git status" is ran with no parameters:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

o = subprocess.check_output("git -c color.status=always status", shell=True)
started = False
done = False
for line in o.split('\n'):
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    if line.strip() == '' and not done:
        if started:
            started = False
            done = True
        started = True
        print(line)
        continue
    if started and 'modified: ' in line:
        filename = line.split('modified:')[1].strip().split('\x1b')[0]
        p = subprocess.Popen(["git", "diff", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = subprocess.check_output("diffstat", stdin=p.stdout).split('|')[1]
        print('%s %s' % (line.rstrip(), out.split('\n')[0]))
    else:
        print(line)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias by placing this line in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    status = !sh -c 'foo $@' --
```

where `foo` is your script, stored somewhere on the PATH. Script `foo` shall recognize if any parameters are passed and use a vanilla `git status` in that case.

Comment: Will this handle situations when I give `git status` an argument and I'd rather it just ran vanilla git-status?

Comment: No. I'll improve it a bit, just a moment.

Comment: @SzG `git` will only look in the alias space for commands that are not already recognized as builtins. This may work on some older versions of `git` (before all the subcommands became builtins), but does not on more recent versions (verified on my current system with `git` 2.1.1).

Comment: Out of luck then, apparently.

Comment: Or you could have an alternative `git` script in your `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`...